# Как заполнить таблицу значениями по умолчанию при создании?

Tags: android, sql

Хочу, чтобы после создания в таблице `SQL` уже были изначальные, дефолтные данные.

Реализую это так: при запуске приложения смотрю, пустая таблица или нет, и отталкиваясь от этого добавляю данные. Но этот способ мне кажется не очень правильным.

Подскажите, как сделать это более красивым способом?

---

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163028/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-sql-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8#comment2017886_1163028):

> У меня в таблице всегда будет только одна строка, в ней только будет меняться значения. Я хочу, чтобы после создания таблицы в ней было не 0 строк, а уже сразу 1 строка.

Comment: 1) Какая СУБД? и версию укажите. 2) Что такое дефолтные данные? в SQL это значение DEFAULT атрибута поля в структуре таблицы (или NULL при его отсутствии).

Comment: А если все данные стерли, то они станут сами дефолтные.

Можно в соседней таблице сохранять факты запполнения.
Если факт есть -- не заполнять.

Плюс _миграции_ --  если в версии 2.0 захочется поменять формат таблицы.

Comment: У меня в таблице всегда будет только одна строка, в ней только будет меняться значения. Я хочу, чтобы после создания таблицы в ней было не 0 строк, а уже сразу 1 строка.

Comment: Вы путаете дефолтность значения с наличием записи в базе. Наверняка это можно сделать красиво в зависимости от стека технологий который вы используете для работы с бд. Мне на ум приходит топорное решение с программным добавлением желаемой строки в базу при её создании.

Answer (score 2):

Если в таблице всегда должна быть только одна строка со значениями по умолчанию, то создавайте таблицу как CTAS (*create-table-as-select*):

```
create table t1 as
    select 'value1' col1, 'value2' col2, 'value3' col3;


select * from t1;

col1    col2    col3
------  ------  ------
value1  value2  value3
```

Чтобы избежать ошибочной вставки или удаления используйте ограничения или триггеры. Что иммено, сильно зависит от брeнда СУБД. Вот [воспроизводимый пример для SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=016148986243afb673fd6caf7dd86643):

```
create trigger delt1 delete on t1 
begin
    select raise (fail, 'illegal delete on t1');
end;

delete from t1;
```

> illegal delete on t1